# How to get active users from last X mins in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have a website created in Django, How can I get a list of active users from last X mins. I want all not-logged in as well as logged-in users.

Comment: are you using the django default user class ? because it has `last_login` field [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login). you can filter using this field. Other way is checking user login session

Comment: @LinhNguyen Actually I don't want to count the logged-in users only. I want to count all the users active on the webpage since the last X minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Django Cache Framework plus using middlewares that you can find them here:
[Django Cache Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/) , 
[Middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/) 
and make a Online User Catcher for every time you want. that was the technical way to implement by yourself

and also the easy way - using third party packages :

**django-online-users** : 
[Github link](https://github.com/lawrencemq/django-online-users)

it's very easy and i'm using it too.